# How do I get back to the Undyne area after going to Snowdin?

Tags: undertale

I'm in Pacifist, and I can't get up the ledge without Monster Kid. I've tried the ferry, the duck, and calling Papyrus but nothing seems to work.

Comment: **please** helpp

Comment: Why does the duck not work? Is it on the wrong side?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to talk with the creature that looks like a Ragnarok Poring? It should be on your left, after you cross the door after the telescope room (and don't worry, it does not cost any money; it will give you money instead).